# Conditionally replace categorical values in R

Tags: r, replace, categorical-data

I'm new to using R and have been consulting this forum for some of my previous R issues. However, I can't seem to find answers to my current one.

I have a big dataset with multiple columns. I want to replace certain values in one column based on values in another column. Here's a sample:

```
organization                                    organization_type                
[1,] "Human Relief Foundation"                  "NGO"                            
[2,] "Management Systems International"         "Other"                          
[3,] "World Vision"                             "NGO"                            
[4,] "European Disaster Volunteers"             "NGO"                            
[5,] "Management Systems International"         "Other"                          
[6,] "International Committee of the Red Cross" "Red Cross/Red Crescent Movement"
[7,] "International Committee of the Red Cross" "Red Cross/Red Crescent Movement"
[8,] "Development Alternatives"                 "Consultancy"
```

The above dataset shows "Other" under organization_type for values "Management Systems International". I'd like replace "Other" with "Consultancy". How can I do that?

I've tried the following as suggested in another forum but it only retained the filtered data:

```
library(dplyr)

data_df <- data_df %>% filter(organization == "Management Systems International" 
           & organization_type == "Other") %>%  
           mutate(organization_type = "Consultancy")
```

Is there a way to "unfilter" data in R to also have the original data entries along with the filtered data? Excel does this but it's hard to process big datasets in Excel.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have a matrix there.  So try `within(as.data.frame(data_df), {
    organization_type[organization_type == "Other" & organization == "Management Systems International"] <- "Consultancy"
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the package `stringr` and `ifelse`.

Your data (subset of it, for illustration purposes).

```
a <- c("Human Relief Foundation", "Management Systems International", "World Vision", "World Vision")   
b <- c("NGO", "Other", "NGO", "Other")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))
df
#                                 a     b
#1          Human Relief Foundation   NGO
#2 Management Systems International Other
#3                     World Vision   NGO
#4                     World Vision Other
```

And then replace specific parts of the data.

```
library(stringr)
df$b <- ifelse(df$a=="Management Systems International", 
   str_replace(as.character(df$b), "Other", "Consultancy"), as.character(df$b))
df
#                                 a           b
#1          Human Relief Foundation         NGO
#2 Management Systems International Consultancy
#3                     World Vision         NGO
#4                     World Vision       Other
```

Comment: Thanks milan! I've tried your code and it totally worked.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `data.table` package, you can do this as follows:

```
# Install if necessary
if (!require("data.table")) install.packages("data.table")
# Load the data.table package
library(data.table)

# Convert data_df to a data.table 
data_dt <- data.table(data_df) %>%
  # Where organization_type equals 'Other', replace organization_type to 'Consultancy'
  .[organization_type == "Other", organization_type := "Consultancy"]

# Print result
print(data_dt)
```

The result:

```
                               organization               organization_type
1:                  Human Relief Foundation                             NGO
2:         Management Systems International                     Consultancy
3:                             World Vision                             NGO
4:             European Disaster Volunteers                             NGO
5:         Management Systems International                     Consultancy
6: International Committee of the Red Cross Red Cross/Red Crescent Movement
7: International Committee of the Red Cross Red Cross/Red Crescent Movement
8:                 Development Alternatives                     Consultancy
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr,

```
data_df %>% mutate(organization_type = ifelse(
      organization == "Management Systems International",
      "Consultancy",
      organization_type))

                              organization               organization_type
1                  Human Relief Foundation                             NGO
2         Management Systems International                     Consultancy
3                             World Vision                             NGO
4             European Disaster Volunteers                             NGO
5         Management Systems International                     Consultancy
6 International Committee of the Red Cross Red Cross/Red Crescent Movement
7 International Committee of the Red Cross Red Cross/Red Crescent Movement
8                 Development Alternatives                     Consultancy
```

Comment: And if the column "organization_type" is a factor, you should do `as.character(organization_type)` instead of `organization_type` in the last line.